# Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to write an eclipse plugin to show the actual value of the message code. The values are to be loaded from the given resource bundle. Only classes of the resource bundle will be available. So I require to load the resource bundle class which is declared in the current file. These class files will be in the classes folder or in a jar file in the lib folder. Is there any way to load the classes dynamically from the eclipse plugin?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

An Example how to get a externalized string from a message.properties file

```
private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "de.stackoverflow.package.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$

private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
```

Every plugin does have a bundle object where you can load the files of a plugin. The Bundle object should contain every information you want to use.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The bundles are available in the output folder of the current project of the workbench. is it possible to load that bundle with the above statement?

Comment: you can load everything which is inside the plugin structure.

Comment: Any idea how to load a class which is available only in one of the Java project available in the eclipse workspace

Comment: i dont now what you want to do?! When Plugin B depend on Plugin A, All classes form B can load the classes from A. Otherwise you have to put the classloader of the plugin the class is lying into the plgin you want to load the class.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Bundle class. There is the following method:

```
public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException;
```

To get the bundle from your plugin:

```
Activator.getDefault().getBundle()
```

Hope this help

Manu